# Predict traffic over a node for the next day given traffic on current day

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics, statistical-inference, average

Suppose I am observing the traffic over a network node every minute of a single day. At the end of the day, I have a table of observations like this:

```
Time     | Traffic
00:00:00 | t1
00:00:01 | t2
.        |
.        |
.        |
23:59:00 | tn
```

What kind of models are there to offer a prediction for the traffic on the next day based on these observations?

The naive approach I can see would be to choose a time interval, say an hour, take an average of the traffic over that hour and use it as my prediction for every minute of the corresponding hour the next day.

(a) Is there anything else you can think of in terms of prediction with this data?

(b) I am also know considering validation. How would you validate this model? Say a model produces predictions, what validation techniques are there given only this dataset? I am thinking cutting it up in between time intervals, so say 16 hours spread throughout the day are chosen to run/train the algorithm, and the remaining hours interspersed throughout the day can be used to validate.

Comment: There are lots of approaches to time series prediction like this. You can do LSTM, ARCH, GARCH, ARMA, ARIMA, various filters, state space approach, and others, no doubt.

Comment: @AdrianKeister thanks, I figure this has some connection to time series and I came across ARIMA, I'm going to look into it closer. 

The interesting thing is also validation, how would you validate the model given only this input? I figured partitioning it in between time intervals, running the algorithm on one set and validating it on the other half, so that times of day are not separated.

Comment: I'd recommend reserving the last, say, tenth or fifth of your data for validation. Because it's time series, you have to keep things chronological.

Comment: @AdrianKeister That's a good point, however from looking at the data there are clear patterns throughout the day, like high traffic during morning and evening. Using morning, afternoon and evening information to predict late night traffic seems to ignore that. Perhaps if I make as little an impact on the chronology as possible while choosing the validation data it would be worthwhile to sacrifice some of the accuracy of the information to gain a little ground on proper validation.

Comment: You should have enough data to encompass any sort of periodic behavior like that. If you don't have several days' worth of data, get more data!

Comment: @AdrianKeister Yeah, outside the scope of this toy problem the answer would be to gather more data, unfortunately I'm restricted to this little scenario, so I'm trying to squeeze anything I can out of it.

Comment: You can always make up your own data: take one day's worth and add a small Gaussian noise to the times.

Comment: Becides daily cycles are there weekly cycles and holiday surgges?

Comment: @WilliamElliot Unfortunately this is a toy problem I was given, any further information I provide I would be making up to give the problem further structure. I was just unfamiliar with the type of stats tools for this kind of problem, I'm currently trying to run ARIMA on it.